# cordova upgrade 4.0 (iOS platform) issue

Tags: cordova, upgrade

I try (as in the past) upgrade cordova to 4.0 for iOS (I'm using the platform guide - non-CLI project).

In the past I did this by downloading / extracting the .tgz file found at:

http://archive.apache.org/dist/cordova/platforms/

and then run the :

bin/update path/to/project

command as defined on page:

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_platforms_ios_upgrade.md.html#Upgrading%20iOS

Easy enough, but I can't seem to find the codova-ios-4.0 tgz file anywhere?

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

The cordova 4.0 you mention is the CLI version, now, every platform has it's own version, that is different from the CLI version. 
Latest iOS version is 3.7.0 http://archive.apache.org/dist/cordova/platforms/cordova-ios-3.7.0.tgz

> Cordova CLI bumped to version 4.0
>
> We have recently decided to update our release process to include
>   independent releases for platforms. This means that our platform
>   maintainers can release updates when they need to and not have to wait
>   for other platforms to be ready to release.

http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2014/10/16/cordova-4.html